# How to determine if the current Drupal page is a contact page?

Tags: 8, emails

With Drupal 8, in THEMENAME.theme I can generate a class based on the current node ID which will be inserted in the body tag :

In the `THEMENAME_preprocess_html()` function, i use :

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if($node) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();
  }
```

But how can i determine if we are on the contact page since it is not a node ?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but... `$contact_form = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form');
```

This returns an object of type `ContactForm` when the user is on a contact page. A simple detection you can do with `getRouteName()`:

```
if ('entity.contact_form.canonical' === \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()) {
  // huhu, a contact form
}
```

You can have a look at `./core/modules/contact/contact.routing.yml`. There are all routes available.

Comment: I had a look at `./core/modules/contact/contact.routing.yml.`and it seems to be the correct answer. But, it doesn’t work in `THEMENAME_preprocess_html()` but i can get the node id. Is there something else i should think off ? I’ve already cleared cache.

Comment: I'm doing this `$contact_form = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form'); if ($contact_form) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'contact-test';
  }`

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I've updated my answer. I tested this on my `THEME_preprocess_html()` and it works well.

Comment: It works but i had to do `if ('contact.site_page' === \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()) {
  // hello contact form
}`